# Add a polygon as a marker in Google Maps Flash Api

Tags: flash, google-maps

I am creating a project in Flash using the Google Maps API and docs.

I'm trying to add a marker to the map, which is draggable but I don't want it to look like the standard Google Maps bubble-style marker.  Is it possible to have a custom polygon or image but still keep the draggability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
[Embed(source="assets/MyIcon.png")] private var myIcon:Class; //defines the marker icon to be used
```

.
.
.

**// then in Your code.**

```
var optObj:Object = new Object();
optObj.icon = new myIcon(); // instance of the myIcon Class
optObj.iconOffset = new Point(-11.5, -17.5); // this is optional, to set center of icon visually
optObj.draggable = true; // this option makes draggable Icon
var latlng = new LatLng(xxx, xxx); // replace xxx with your lat/lng values.
var marker:Marker = new Marker(latlng, new MarkerOptions(tmpObj));
map.addOverlay(marker); // adds the marker to your overlay
```

This is the way i do it, hope You find it usefull.

Regards.

Omar Guzmán.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a Polygon as a Marker icon, although I have't tried it. The MarkerOptions class lets you specify a DisplayObject to be used instead of the default bubble marker...that's probably you're easiest solution.

One thing you could do if you wanted a more complex Marker is to create your own CustomMarker class which extends Marker. This way you can add extra functionality.

Lewis